# Generics in actionscript (return type the same as parameter type)

Tags: actionscript

Is it possible to specify that a return type of a function is the same as one of the parameter types where it is unknown what the parameter type is. For example:

```
class Factory {
    public function get(interface:*):Object {
    }
}
```

The problem with the above is that I have to cast the object to interface all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do this?:

```
function example(type:*):*
{
    return type;
}
```

Doesn't seem to require casting:

```
trace(example(new Sprite()).alpha); // 1
```

Comment: those are called kissing types :D